# Set up ghost blog on subdirectory of a laravel website with nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, ghost

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with nginx.
My website is built with laravel and it works as you would expect: example.com, example.com/page, etc all works

What I'm trying to do is the following:
Every page on example.com should be served by laravel, except example.com/blog. the /blog should be served by Ghost.

The location of the websites are:

- /var/www/laravel(/public) for the main site
- /var/www/ghost for the blog

I managed to successfully install Ghost on a subdomain (ghost.example.com), thanks to the help of this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-blog-with-ghost-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Right now when I go to example.com/blog it links to example.com

This is my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;

    server_name example.com;

    include hhvm.conf;

    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

    root /var/www/laravel/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {

       # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
       try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }

    location ^~ /blog {
        # this works perfectly
        # return 301 http://www.google.com;

        # I got this code from the tutorial

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;

   }

    # Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

The ghost config file:

```
 production: {
        url: 'https://example.com/blog',
        mail: {},
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },

        server: {
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            port: '2368'
        }
    },
```

Comment: Try moving the `^~ /blog` location block above the `/` location block.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on [how to install Ghost in a subdirectory](https://allaboutghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-in-a-subdirectory/)

Comment: @Bogdan, still the same.. example.com/blog redirects to example.com

Comment: Thanks @morphatic, I managed to set Ghost up in a subdirectory on another server, but as soon I try it with the setup mentioned in the OP, something goes wrong